# ConnectionStringSettings NullReference Error

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, web-config

I have the following settings in my web.config, as a child of the configuration element:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <clear />
  <add name="GingerlimeDB"
       connectionString="Data Source=localhost;
                       Integrated Security=False;
                       Initial Catalog=dbname;
                       User Id=accountname;
                       Password=password;"
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

In the code behind where I wish to retrieve the connection string, I placed:

```
using System.Configuration
...
    var connStringObject = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GingerlimeDB"];
    string connectionString = connStringObject.ConnectionString;
    Console.WriteLine(connectionString);
```

I don't get to the console output, instead it shows:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

How do I get the Connection String out of the web config?

Comment: Is the configuration section defined in the `web.config` under the `configSections` element?

Comment: No it is not. I take it it should be. Right now it's under the configuration element.

Comment: Or do you mean "under" as in underneath, instead of nested. It was "under" the configSections element.

Comment: I mean, is there a `section` element with `name="connectionStrings"` in the `web.config` under `configuration\configSections\sectionGroup`?

Comment: There should be. Where did you get this config from?

Comment: They are not as important, but I believe one should be there.

Comment: I think the web.config came with Visual Web Developer. Now I'm working in Visual Studio but I'm still using the old file. I think that's what happened. Either that or I created a new project in Visual Studio 2008. This goes a couple of weeks back.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `web.config` file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <clear />
        <add name="GingerlimeDB"
                   connectionString="Data Source=localhost;
                   Integrated Security=False;
                   Initial Catalog=dbname;
                   User Id=accountname;
                   Password=password;"
                   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

You *should* be able to access the connection string exactly like you showed in your code. I use something nearly identical:

```
using System.Configuration;
....
internal bool OpenDatabaseConnection()
{
        try
        {
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabase"].ConnectionString;
            dbConnection = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString);
            dbConnection.Open();
            return true;
        }
        catch (SqlCeException ex)
        {
            this.errorLogging = new ErrorLogging(ex.Message, ex.Source, ex.HelpLink, ex.GetType().ToString());
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
        {
            this.errorLogging = new ErrorLogging(ex.Message, ex.Source, ex.HelpLink, ex.GetType().ToString());
        }
        catch (ArgumentException ex)
        {
            this.errorLogging = new ErrorLogging(ex.Message, ex.Source, ex.HelpLink, ex.GetType().ToString());
        }
        catch (ConfigurationErrorsException ex)
        {
            this.errorLogging = new ErrorLogging(ex.Message, ex.Source, ex.HelpLink, ex.GetType().ToString());
        }
        return false;
}
```

Which line is actually causing the NullReference exception? (object not set to an instance of an object)?

Comment: That would be the connStringObject line. I separated them out for easier debugging. It seems there isn't a connStringSettings (named connStringObject in my case) returned from the ConfigurationManager.ConfigurationString[...].

Comment: Another test (if connStringObject == null) confirmed the above. For some reason the ConnectionString isn't found.

Comment: @herrturtur Check the "build action" of your web.config file - it should be set to "content".

Comment: @Jared_Harley "build action" property is set to "content".